# Wicket tabbed panel/wizard not rendered in the correct position

Tags: java, css, wicket

I've got a layout problem. I'm trying to put a dynamic wizard on one of of the tabs in a tabbed panel.
Problem is, as you can see the wizard content is positioned at the wrong location. After some inspection with Firebug, it's caused by a couple of `<div>` elements (one hightlighted in the Firebug window) which have a css style position value of 'absolute'.

If I remove the position attribute, using the Firebug style editor, then the wizard content shifts down and is positioned perfectly within the tab.

I don't know what has inserted these divs, or how I control the style attribute for these elements.

[image: layout problem]

Answer (score 0):

These are hidden fields used by Form#writeHiddenFields() for some form trickery. They should not corrupt your layout.

I'd expect the floating tab-links in your TabbedPanel's CSS to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that those hidden fields are corrupting the layout. Taking off the 'absolute' position attribute sorts out the problem. I'll take a look at the CSS for the tab links though.